# Java Selenium 3 vs Selenium 4 - ChromeOptions and DesiredCapabilities

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, desiredcapabilities

In my current project I use selenium 3 and I want to update to selenium 4.

I have to convert the following code to selenium 4.

Old code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--incognito");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Now selenium 4 code - Can you tell me if this code is correct ?

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--incognito");
options.addArguments("--enable-javascript");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
options.merge(capabilities);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Is the new code correct ?
Is the "merge" function correct ?
I see that "`CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true`" is depreciated in Selenium 4 and does not work - is there any replacement for this ? What was it doing ?
What does actually do "`capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true)`" ?

Is is possible that option "`capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);`" may cause erros along with the following wait code ?

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, MyDefaultTimeout).Until(
d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor) d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
```